# Validation in MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

`enter code here`I use client side form validation, but it's not working.

My Model:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\.]*$",ErrorMessage="Error")]
public string Scode { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@using(Html.BeginForm("CreateSharshomari", "VahedInfo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Scode")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Scode")

    <input id="BtnErsal" type="submit" value="ارسال" />
}
```

What could be wrong?

its my controller.i think perhaps i have a problem about it . please look at it and say your opinion .

```
    public PartialViewResult CreateSharshomari()
    {
        IEnumerable<Lcity> Lcitys = Dbcon.Lcitys;
        IEnumerable<RFaaliat> RFaaliats = Dbcon.RFaaliats;

        var query = Lcitys.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Citycode.ToString(),
                Text = x.CityName,
                Selected = x.Citycode == 1
            });
        var query1 = RFaaliats.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.IDReshteh.ToString(),
                Text = x.ReshteName,
                Selected = x.IDReshteh == 1
            });

        var model = new CityFaaliatViewModel
        {
            Lcitylist = query.AsEnumerable(),
            RFaaliatList = query1.AsEnumerable()
        };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSharshomari(TaavoniInfo Info,CityFaaliatViewModel selcode)
    {
        try
        {
            TaavoniInfo idcity = Info;
            idcity.idCitycode = Convert.ToInt32(selcode.SelectedCitycode);
            idcity.idIDReshteh = Convert.ToInt32(selcode.SelectedIDReshteh);
           Dbcon.TaavoniInfos.Add(idcity);
            Dbcon.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.SuccessMsg = "success";
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.SuccessMsg = "error";
            return View();
        }
   }
```

please help me.

Comment: Have you imported `jqueryval` bundle on that page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported required jQuery files as below? If not , then I would invite you to do so.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Given your model:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
  [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\.]*$",ErrorMessage="Error")]
  public string Scode { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model SomeAppName.Models.MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using(Html.BeginForm("CreateSharshomari", "VahedInfo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.TextBox("Scode")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Scode")

    <input id="BtnErsal" type="submit" value="ارسال" />
}
```

Note that you must have following keys in the `Web.config` file, for validtion to work on client side:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Or in the App_Start

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
   //Enable or Disable Client Side Validation at Application Level
   HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
   HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help ,but i imported library in pages but not solved my problem .

Comment: @Raly Have you already imported Jquery before all these?If no, import it.

Comment: perhaps my controller has a problem i dont know

Comment: @Raly Check once, if you have done all these things, them there might be a problem

Comment: @Raly Why are you passing two models to `CreateSharshomari` method using POST?

Comment: because i have two dropdown in my viewmodel and i want send selected key for saving in database